# What is the best way to pass functions between inner components in AngularJS 1.5?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-compile, angularjs-components

I was wondering what is the best way to pass functions down through 2 or more levels of components? There's no simple way of skipping the function wrap when using '&' bindings?

Here's an use case:

```
angular.module('app', []).component('app', {
  controller: class AppController {
    doSomething (data) {}
  },
  template: `
    <sub-component on-do-something="$ctrl.doSomething(data)">
    </sub-component>
  `
})
```

ps: I'm using ngRedux, so such scenario is very common

EDIT:

The problem is: for the code above to work, each inner component controller would look like this:

```
.component('subComponent', {
    bindings: {
        doSomething: '&'
    },
    controller: function SubComponentController () {
        this._doSomething = param => this.doSomething({data: param});
    },
    template: `
        <inner-component do-something="$ctrl._doSomething(data)">
        </inner-component>
    `
});

.component('innerComponent', {
    bindings: {
        doSomething: '&'
    },
    controller: function InnerComponentController () {
        this._doSomething = param => this.doSomething({data: param});
    },
    template: `
        <sub-inner-component do-something="$ctrl._doSomething(data)">
        </sub-inner-component>
    `
});
```

And then I'd have to pass down `_doSomething` instead of `doSomething` directly.

ps: I'm not using transclusion here

Comment: @DmitriZaitsev that isn't the ideal solution given that I'm using redux and the concepts of smart & dumb components :(

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the function wrap?

Comment: Also it is not clear from your example whether the inner HTML is transcluded or whether it is part of the inner components' templates.

Comment: @PeteBD I am editing the question right now :)

Comment: You can pass data via props or services aka Redux stores.

Comment: @PeteBD added more info, please refresh! And thanks for your help

Answer (score 34, accepted):

It is not necessary to provide a wrapper function in the controller of your sub-components. By using `bindings` a function is automatically attached to the controller, which you can call directly from your template.

The only wrinkle is that this function takes an object, which contains the locals that will be made available to the expression in the outer template.

In this case the `data` variable in the outer template needs to be provided explicitly when call the the `doSomething(locals)` method.

```
angular.module('app', [])

.component('app', {
  controller: class AppController {
    doSomething (data) {
      console.log(data);
    }
  },
  template: `
    <sub-component do-something="$ctrl.doSomething(data)">
    </sub-component>
  `
})

.component('subComponent', {
    bindings: {
        doSomething: '&'
    },
    template: `
        <inner-component do-something="$ctrl.doSomething({data: data})">
        </inner-component>
    `
})

.component('innerComponent', {
    bindings: {
        doSomething: '&'
    },
    template: `
        <sub-inner-component do-something="$ctrl.doSomething({data: data})">
        </sub-inner-component>
    `
})

.component('subInnerComponent', {
  bindings: {
    doSomething: '&'
  },
  template: `
      <button ng-click="$ctrl.doSomething({data: 123})">Do Something</button>
  `
});
```

Here is a working Plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/QQF9jDGf6yiewCRs1EDu?p=preview

Comment: Wow. It still gets a little bit confusing when I think about how Angular translates the initial `{data: 123}` to local variables in the parent expression, but it works. I guess I'll be digging a little bit more in Angular source until I fully understand. Thanks @PeteBD

Comment: Great example. Biiiiiiiiiiiiig like :)